# Play Framework: Result and Result.Status

Tags: java, playframework, httprequest

I'm trying the very first example of play framework and I got this error

In my routes file:

```
# API
# ~~~~
GET   /api/geotweets/index  controllers.api.GeoTweetController.index()
```

In my controller (app/controllers/api/GeoTweetController)

```
public static Result index() {
    return ok("It works!");
}
```

And the compile error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Results.Status to Result`

So I change the index action to:

```
public static Result index() {
  return (Result) ok("It works!");
}
```

But in the play console I got this msg: `Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.Result as an Handler`

All I want to do is to return a simple JSON response (I will try it when I become capable of a simple "hello world"), smth like

```
public static Result index() {
    ArrayList<Object> geoTweets = MyClass.getAllGeoTweets();
    JsonNode response = MyHelper.asJson(geoTweets);
    return Results.ok(response);    
}
```

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playframework supports both Scala and Java, so make sure you are importing the correct `Result` class.

```
// Java
import play.mvc.Result;
```

The Scala classes will be under `play.api.*`.

```
// Scala
import play.api.mvc.Result
```

Comment: Solved, I didn't realize the imports